# Blogs.sun.com is dead

Tags: support, status-completed, hyperlinks, broken-link

Long live https://blogs.oracle.com.

It appears that blogs.sun.com URLs no longer work. They are now blogs.oracle.com.

An Oracle employee is working his way through the relatively small number on ServerFault; however, SO has [800+ links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*blogs.sun.com*%22) and there may be others throughout the network.

I've randomly checked a sample of the links and simply changing sun to oracle fixes them.

The problem ones are like this http://blogs.sun.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans which should now be http://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans

Can someone with suitable powers fix the links network wide?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APV6x.png]

Comment: This is a brilliant and eco-friendly move on Oracle's part. Everyone knows that header redirects are extremely energy intensive. Breaking a million links Internet wide is the much more sustainable option

Comment: I just hit that url and it redirected me, after warning me that there was a security issue. While not technically "broken", they should definitely be fixed...

Comment: @jmort253: Which URL? The problem ones are like this http://blogs.sun.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans which should now be http://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans

Comment: Someone is being extremely stupid. Redirects do happen, just direct to https://blogs.oracle.com/roller-ui/errors/404.jsp.

Comment: Meanwhile in the Oracle Headquarter: "Whaaat? I've just read on the Internet that our links on Stack Overflow are broken!? Call the same guy in cubicle #123125 that has fixed the Server Fault links and order him to fix also the other 800+ links. Nooow!"

Comment: Note that while changing blogs.sun.com to blogs.oracle.com works in most cases, there are some exceptions - blogs of long gone employees were purged unless specially chosen to be saved, and some blogs had to be renamed due to conflicts with existing blogs.oracle.com blogs in the site merge.   For instance, there was already https://blogs.oracle.com/security/ so what was http://blogs.sun.com/security/ became https://blogs.oracle.com/sunsecurity/ instead.   Also if you want to save a redirect, all Oracle blogs now use https and redirect http URL's to https.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: This isn't really status-completed. Note my request was for a network wide fix. There are still some on SF and possibly elsewhere too. IF you could provide an answer too I can accept.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  It took me the better part of a week to fix the links on SO, so I forgot about the "network-wide" bit.  I removed the status tag for now.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Wow - heroic editing. Given the size of the job I was hoping someone with database access would step up and do it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard this is now complete, I just finished checking all the SE sites. Can you please provide an answer so I can accept it and mark this as status-completed - thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The broken links have been fixed across the network.  Thanks to everyone who pitched in.

Answer (score 23):

We should complain to Oracle that they messed up their redirects.

Currently, `http://blogs.sun.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans` redirects to `https://blogs.sun.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans`, which redirects to `https://blogs.oracle.com/roller-ui/errors/404.jsp` (which despite the filename, responds with HTTP 200). (checked using `wget 'http://blogs.sun.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans' --no-check-certificate`)

They should be able to fix it trivially.

Comment: I honestly don't think they messed up.

Comment: @Iain why? Putting up redirects when you move content should be done by any competent webmaster.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Unless of course you want to expunge the original urls.

Comment: @Iain: Whatever there intentions are, the certificate error is a clear sign of somebody messing up.

Comment: @CodesInChaos "why?" - yes they've made a mess of a lot of people's links. But you don't do something like this by accident, so clearly they're doing exactly what they want to do. It's just that they want to do something stupid. But they haven't "messed up" in the sense of making something that they will see as an error and want to fix.

Comment: @DJPon3: re: "you don't do something like this by accident": just because they are a company with many smart, technically competent people doesn't mean that they assigned the website migration task to a smart, technically competent person. it could very easily be an accident

Comment: @kip - from what I've seen, big companies like that tend to have every little click of the mouse overseen by about 50 different people when it comes to stuff that's visible to the public.

Comment: Sun/Oracle employees with blogs (such as myself) received notice earlier this year that "blogs.sun.com > blogs.oracle.com redirects will expire on Feb 10, 2012." and that we needed to "change any external links to blogs.oracle.com (from blogs.sun.com)."   We already complained at the site maintainers who announced that, and it didn't help.

Comment: @alanc I'm not surprised. I'm a little saddened to see an era end though.

Answer (score 1):

The `http://download-llnw.oracle.com` is also dead (well, actually, it returns HTTP 400 "Invalid URL"). We should [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*download-llnw.oracle.com*%22&submit=search) it by `http://docs.oracle.com`. I just started editing a few of my posts, but I've hit the demotivating "max 5 edits on own posts per day" barrier too soon.

---

The `http://download.oracle.com` currently redirects to `http://docs.oracle.com` (by 302, not by 301 :/ ). Let's hope that it won't die sooner or later as there are currently [5000+ links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*download.oracle.com*%22&submit=search) to it...