# "Writing the perfect question" link on the "How to Ask" page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center, broken-link

The [*How to Ask* page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?) (the one presented when new users try to ask a question) contains a sidebar with helpful links:

> ### Related
>
> [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
>
> [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
>
> [Help vampires: a spotter’s guide](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
>
> [How to ask a question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375)

Unfortunately, [Jon just moved blog platforms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237110/is-there-any-support-for-mass-link-editing) and the link to his *Writing the perfect question* is now less perfect, as in: *totally broken*.

Can it be repointed to the new location at http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We caught that elsewhere - places that are not hard coded.

Missed this one.

With you in the next build.