# link to 'Writing the perfect question' by Jon Skeet is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center, broken-link

While reading **[Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)**, I found that '**[Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)**' by Jon Skeet is not working in help message.

See the following screenshots:

> [image]

when I opened the link, I found `Server Error` message:

> [image]

I am just trying to catch the eye of moderators on the bug.

Comment: Related: ["Writing the perfect question" link on the "How to Ask" page is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237635)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct location to report this; it is a network-wide bug. You just found one more location to fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jon recently [moved his blog](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/25/new-blog-hosting/), and there are some links around that have not been moved.

I thought we did this one - we have now.