# Jon Skeet's Area 51 flair now shows 1000k reputation!

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun

As can be seen [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top), Jon Skeet's  Area 51 flair now shows 1000k reputation!<sup>1</sup>

> [image]

This reputation consists of:

- 847k rep on Stack Overflow
- 142k rep on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow <sup>2</sup>
- 4k rep on Super User, 3k on Programmers and 3k on Server Fault.
- 1k combined on other sides, namely Code Review, Mi Yodeya, PPCG and Stack Apps.

Congratulations and thanks to Jon Skeet for reaching this amazing number and for all his work he has done for Stack Exchange!

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup> Once his reputation goes over 1,000,000 rep, the Area 51 flair will show 1.0m. Now it is at 999,732 reputation, so it rounds to 1000k.

<sup>2</sup> Meta Stack Overflow once had reputation points, and this is taken into account in the calculation.

Comment: Link to the page with the flair, please? :)

Comment: @Dawny33 http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=commitment

Comment: Thanks!  Oh boy, he skewed his entire div big time :D

Comment: lol, Jeff got 2.4m due to referring Jon to that proposal... :D

Comment: I was expecting [meta-tag:bug] tag, but then I saw [tag:fun]. So, congratulation, Jon!