# Please fix the links to Michael Kaplan’s blog network-wide

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, hyperlinks, broken-link

The blog has moved and old links no longer work, but fortunately they can be machine-updated to the new ones. One needs to change

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/*
```

and

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/*
```

to

```
http://www.siao2.com/*
```

[Also, a precedent.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141203/171857)

Comment: rip Michael Kaplan. 1970—2015

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is done. Big thanks to Jarrod Dixon for making a tool for doing simple URL search-and-replace across multiple posts!

Comment: Ok, *now* it's done.

Comment: I've cleaned up what I could find remaining manually, @kinokijuf - I'm afraid that's gonna have to do for what's left.

Comment: Nick Craver coded the back-end (the most difficult part) before going on paternity leave; I only put a front-end on it.